# List Properties of Object in Velocity Template

Tags: velocity

We're working on a project that uses Velocity for its display templates. Unfortunately, there is no documentation concerning what properties are available on objects, which makes it fairly difficult to write these templates.

Is it possible to use Velocity to produce a list of the properties on an object? If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, which objects do you mean? Your own objects that you pass to a template? Well all public methods are available, just like if you were calling them from Java.

Comment: Yes, I mean objects passed to the template. Unfortunately, I do not know what the public methods of the object are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ClassTool.html

Comment: Indeed I am. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Just add an instance to your context, either manually or automatically via VelocityTools.

```context.put('class', new ClassTool());```